# Making a graph complete

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Here's my issue: I created this graph by the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \newdimen\R
   \R=1.3cm
   \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) };
   \foreach \x/\l/\p in
     { 60/{$\overline{3}$}/above,
      120/{$2$}/above,
      180/{$1$}/left,
      240/{$3$}/below,
      300/{$\overline{2}$}/below,
      360/{$\overline{1}$}/right
     }
     \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] at (\x:\R) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Now, I would like to add edges between all of the vertices, but I am stuck at how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} \newdimen\R
       \R=1.3cm
       \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) };
       \foreach \x/\l/\p in
         { 60/{$\overline{3}$}/above,
          120/{$2$}/above,
          180/{$1$}/left,
          240/{$3$}/below,
          300/{$\overline{2}$}/below,
          360/{$\overline{1}$}/right
         }
         \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] at (\x:\R) {}; 
         \foreach \x in {60, 120, ..., 360} {
            \draw (\x:\R) -- (\x+120:\R);
            \draw (\x:\R) -- (\x+180:\R);
         }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just iterate around the circle again but connect every other node and then again but skipping two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you already accepted Willoughby's answer, I let another solution, maybe more versatile and with a better alignment for the figures.
[image: complete graph]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\r{2}
        \foreach \c [count=\i from 0] in {
            $\overline{1}$,
            $\overline{3}$,
            $2$,
            $1$,
            $3$,
            $\overline{2}$}
            {
            \path (0,0) -- (60*\i:\r) node[circle,inner sep=1mm,fill=black](\i){} --++ (60*\i:10pt) node{\c};
            }
            \foreach \i in {0,...,5}
                \foreach \n in {\i,...,5}
                    \draw (\i.center) -- (\n.center);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```